# Error 400 Bad Request - individual redirect

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, http-error

The Seo Company ask for making redirect each 404 bad request to specific url.
I asked for redirect an error 400 (Bad request) to special page.

I can do it in the web.config file, but the requirement is each url to special page
for example
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/askhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask =>(301) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
https://stackoverflow.com/questionshttps://stackoverflow.com/questions => (301) https://stackoverflow.com/questions

Is it possible?
My application is ASP.NET (Not MVC) on IIS SERVER

Thanks

Comment: ASP.NET what then?

Comment: It's worth pointing out that you mention 404 (which is not found) and 400 (which is bad request). Typically you'd only want to redirect 404s because a 400 is likely to be a symptom of an issue in your application. Anyway, answer below...

Answer (score 0):

**Caveat:**

You say this is "ASP.NET (not MVC)". I'm going to assume this means you're using WebForms rather than ASP.NET Core. The following advice can be used in both cases, but in case of ASP.NET Core only if you're hosting with IIS.

**Answer:**

You're looking for IIS [URL Rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), a module that can be installed in IIS then configured via your `web.config`. One feature this provides is rewrite maps which are essentially a list of *from* and *to* URL mappings where a request for the former will cause a redirect to the latter. The [documentation for URL Rewrite maps is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module), and here's an example from the documentation:

Define your mappings:

```
<rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="StaticRewrites" defaultValue="">
            <add key="/article1" value="/article.aspx?id=1&amp;title=some-title" />
            <add key="/some-title" value="/article.aspx?id=1&amp;title=some-title" />
            <add key="/post/some-title.html" value="/article.aspx?id=1&amp;title=some-title" />
        </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Then add a rewrite rule to use the mappings you just defined:

```
<rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite Rule">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{StaticRewrites:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

In your case you'll want to use the `Redirect` action rather than `Rewrite`.

The module provides a lot of other configuration options.

Comment: Thanks, but does the url rewrite work with error 400 for example from http://www.example.com/pagehttp://www? to http://www.example.com/page

Comment: It'll map any *known* failing URL to another URL (regardless of the status code that URL would otherwise respond with). So if you know you have a referrer requesting a specific bad URL you could add it to your map. But URL Rewrite rules are only based on parsing the requested URL. If you included example.com/pagehttp://www as a source URL in a rewrite map then the status code for that URL's response would become 301 (assuming you want a permanent redirect)

Answer (score 0):

On asp.net webforms set a page i.e. Redirect.aspx to redirect all the Error of type 400:

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
   <customErrors defaultRedirect="Error.htm"
                 mode="RemoteOnly">
     <error statusCode="400"
            redirect="Redirect.aspx"/>
   </customErrors>
 </system.web>
```

then on the page see the Url it cames from by:

```
Request.UrlReferrer
```

then handle accordingly