# How to redirect to homepage when url response status code is 400 using middleware in C# .Net Core 5 Blazor Server Side App

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

I am trying to access a page that is returning a 400 status code and then to subsequently redirect the user to homepage via middleware. Here is an example url that will throw a 400: https://testsite.com/%C3%85%C2%81%C3%83%C2%B3d%C3%85%C2%BA_Voivodeship

Note that tacking on "/%C3%85%C2%81%C3%83%C2%B3d%C3%85%C2%BA_Voivodeship" to a request on your blazor server side app/.net mvc application will throw a 400 error.

The url mentioned is present in a sitemap along with many other urls returning a 400 status code. Merely removing the urls from the sitemap is not sufficient in a practical, useful context because search engines have already read them and will continue requesting them. On top of this SEO concern, there is the obvious, but unfortunately not mentioned enough, extremely poor user experience of serving out a "Bad Request - Invalid URL
HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid." error message for any user-facing application.  This just leaves the user stranded.

So, this issue does need to be dealt with when requested in order to course correct the user to a location where they could do something and also to help search engines that crawl websites to strongly indicate that a specific url should not be crawled any longer through a redirect(yes, for those uninformed of technical SEO, this is the correct, best-practice way to handle this scenario).

I tried to accomplish this by placing a app.use in the Configure method of Startup.cs but it never actually hits the code if you use a url like mentioned above. I am able to break; however, for any ordinary request like a 200 status code one. So, it would seem, this is not the right approach to take. Any ideas?

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                var statusCode = context.Response.StatusCode;

                // Redirect to homepage of site when 400 status code
                if (statusCode == 400)
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("/");
                    return;   // short circuit
                }
                await next();
            });
```

Comment: Does the lambda expression you pass to `app.Use` have to be `async`?

Comment: Perhaps. Although I am struggling with how to write it.

Comment: Um, remove the `async` and `await`?

Comment: Doesn't work that simply

Comment: What happens?  Same thing?

Comment: `async` and `await` introduce a lot of complexity under the hood, complexity that is only justified if you *actually* need the thing to be `async`.

Comment: I recommend you test it out. There are multiple error messages. It becomes a task when you remove the async part

Comment: I don't understand why async...await would be the issue. It's never hitting it at all, wouldn't have reached the code eventually...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54044061

Comment: Intuitively, I feel like `async` and `await` should be a matched pair.  If there are code paths that are never going to `await`...

Comment: Link is not useful. That is basic redirect on a blazor component. I am specifically talking about middle ware here and a specific status code, 400

Comment: That was pretty fast.  Are you sure you looked over that post carefully?

Comment: Yes, I have spent a thousand hours in blazor development. Easy to spot when something is not in the ball park

Comment: The blazor part shouldn't be that relevant since we are talking about middleware. Same issue would surface on any .net core web app, by default

Comment: What class is `app`?

Comment: Also, what prevents you from handling this in the Controller?

Comment: Are you familiar with startup.cs file for a .net core project? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: This is a Blazor Server Side Application not an MVC application. I don't think you really have the expertise I am looking for here. I don't think you fundamentally have .net core middleware experience or general knowledge of blazor

Comment: Fair enough, I'll stop helping.

Comment: I do appreciate your willingness to help

Comment: I will merely point out that, in the many examples shown at the page you linked, there isn't a single one containing an orphaned `await` clause.

Comment: I do think that is besides the point. Every example is async await on that page. Furthermore, as mentioned in post, placing a breakpoint inside app.use will never reach the code when there is a 400 error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50017515

Comment: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/web-config-customerrors-in-aspnet-mvc

Comment: https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2017/03/20/custom-error-pages-asp-net-core/ ... Look in the section labelled "Custom Middleware."

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have tested the web.config recommendations. None of those work. I have tested the "Custom Middleware" one as well as that is most closely related to my posted code, but that also had no effect. I have tested the app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects ones before and I just tested one of those now, but have not gotten that one to work, but that is the one I am actively pursuing

Comment: If I cannot get it to work, I will wait a couple days and post on Microsoft's github

Comment: Please call `await next();` prior reading `context.Response.StatusCode`, simply move this line to very top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTTP status code 400 and corresponding message are generated by HTTP.SYS. HTTP.SYS performs URL validation and can reject the request. In such case the returned web page looks like

> Bad Request - Invalid URL
>
> ---
>
> HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

As the specified URL is blocked by HTTP.SYS, request never comes to application. Please see the similar question [%09 in a URL causes IIS (HTTP.SYS?) to return HTTP 400 immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19534080/09-in-a-url-causes-iis-http-sys-to-return-http-400-immediately) for additional details. In the current case, HTTP.SYS does not like %81, %83, %85 characters.
And the corresponding messages can be found in the HTTP.SYS log located at `%SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR`.

If by some reason URL cannot be changed, the HTTP.SYS behavior can be configured via `AllowRestrictedChars` DWORD registry key located under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP\Parameters` as described in [Http.sys registry settings for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/iis/httpsys-registry-windows) article.

> If nonzero, Http.sys accepts hex-escaped chars in request URLs that decode to U+0000 - U+001F and U+007F - U+009F ranges.

The HTTP service must be restarted for the changes to take effect.

Additionally to HTTP.SYS configuration change, the middleware code needs a little improvement. The execution of the `next` delegate needs to be moved to the very top of the method.

```
app.Use(
  async (context, next) =>
  {
    await next();

    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 400)
    {
      context.Response.Redirect("/");
    }
  });
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, the position of the middleware is important. The [`HttpResponse.Redirect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httpresponse.redirect) method simply sets the HTTP status code to `301` or `302` and specifies the `Location` header. If a response has already been sent to the client by other middleware or application code, the `HttpResponse.Redirect` method will throw an exception.